# How to combine multiple numpy arrays into a dictionary list

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have the following array:

```
column_names = ['id', 'temperature', 'price']
```

And three numpy array as follows:

```
idArry = ([1,2,3,4,....])

tempArry = ([20.3,30.4,50.4,.....])

priceArry = ([1.2,3.5,2.3,.....])
```

I wanted to combine the above into a dictionary as follows:

```
table_dict = ( {'id':1, 'temperature':20.3, 'price':1.2 },
               {'id':2, 'temperature':30.4, 'price':3.5},...)
```

I can use a `for` loop together with `append` to create the dictionary but the list is huge at about 15000 rows. Can someone show me how to use python `zip` functionality or other more efficient and fast way to achieve the above requirement?

Comment: Do you need a list of dicts or a tuple of dicts? In your case you have a tuple.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a listcomp and the function `zip()`:

```
[{'id': i, 'temperature': j, 'price': k} for i, j, k in zip(idArry, tempArry, priceArry)]
# [{'id': 1, 'temperature': 20.3, 'price': 1.2}, {'id': 2, 'temperature': 30.4, 'price': 3.5}]
```

If your ids are 1, 2, 3... and you use a list you don’t need ids in your dicts. This is a redundant information in the list.

```
[{'temperature': i, 'price': j} for i, j in zip(tempArry, priceArry)]
```

You can use also a dict of dicts. The lookup in the dict must be faster than in the list.

```
{i: {'temperature': j, 'price': k} for i, j, k in zip(idArry, tempArry, priceArry)}
# {1: {'temperature': 20.3, 'price': 1.2}, 2: {'temperature': 30.4, 'price': 3.5}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work. Enumerate is used to create a counter that starts at 0 and then each applicable value is pulled out of your tempArry and priceArray. This also creates a generator expression which helps with memory (especially if your lists are really large).

```
new_dict = ({'id': i + 1 , 'temperature': tempArry[i], 'price': priceArry[i]} for i, _ in enumerate(idArry))
```

Comment: The ids of OP start with 1 and your ids start with 0.

Comment: @MykolaZotko sorry, didn't notice that. Its fixed now to have the ID's start at 1.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at the functionality of the `pandas` package. In particular there is a [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method.

I'm confident that for large arrays this method should be pretty fast (though I'm willing to have the zip method proved more efficient).

In the example below I first construct a pandas dataframe from your arrays and then use the `to_dict` method.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

column_names = ['id', 'temperature', 'price']

idArry = np.array([1, 2, 3])
tempArry = np.array([20.3, 30.4, 50.4])
priceArry = np.array([1.2, 3.5, 2.3])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([idArry, tempArry, priceArry]).T, columns=column_names)

table_dict = df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list-comprehension to achieve this by just iterating over one of the arrays:

```
[{'id': idArry[i], 'temperature': tempArry[i], 'price': priceArry[i]} for i in range(len(idArry))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build a NumPy matrix then convert to a dictionary as follow. Given your data (I changed the values just for example):

```
import numpy as np

idArry = np.array([1,2,3,4])
tempArry = np.array([20,30,50,40])
priceArry = np.array([200,300,100,400])
```

Build the matrix:

```
table = np.array([idArry, tempArry, priceArry]).transpose()
```

Create the dictionary:

```
dict_table = [ dict(zip(column_names, values)) for values in table ]
#=> [{'id': 2, 'temperature': 30, 'price': 300}, {'id': 3, 'temperature': 50, 'price': 100}, {'id': 4, 'temperature': 40, 'price': 400}]
```

---

I don't know the purpose, but maybe you can also use the matrix as follow.

```
temp_col = table[:,1]

table[temp_col >= 40]
# [[  3  50 100]
#  [  4  40 400]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to do it would be as follows:

```
column_names = ['id', 'temperature', 'price']

idArry = ([1,2,3,4])
tempArry = ([20.3,30.4,50.4, 4])
priceArry = ([1.2,3.5,2.3, 4.5])
```

You could `zip` all elements in the different list:

```
l = zip(idArry,tempArry,priceArry)

print(list(l))
[(1, 20.3, 1.2), (2, 30.4, 3.5), (3, 50.4, 2.3), (4, 4, 4.5)]
```

And append the inner dictionaries to a list using a *list comprehension* and  by iterating over the elements in `l` as so:

```
[dict(zip(column_names, next(l))) for i in range(len(idArry))]

[{'id': 1, 'temperature': 20.3, 'price': 1.2},
 {'id': 2, 'temperature': 30.4, 'price': 3.5},
 {'id': 3, 'temperature': 50.4, 'price': 2.3},
 {'id': 4, 'temperature': 4, 'price': 4.5}]
```

---

The advantage of using this method is that it only uses built-in methods and that it works for an arbitrary amount of `column_names`.